# Mock final private variable using Mockito/Powermock framework

Tags: java, mockito

I'm trying to mock a class that looks like below

```
public class MessageContainer {
  private final MessageChain[] messages;


  MessageContainer(final int numOfMessages, final MessageManagerImpl manager, final Object someOtherStuff) {
    messages = new MessageChain[numOfMessages]
    // do other stuff
  }

  public void foo(final int index) {
    // do something
    messages[index] = getActiveMessage();
  }
}
```

My test code would be as followed:

```
@Test
public void testFoo() {
  MessageContainer messageContainer = Mockito.mock(MessageContainer.class);
  Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(messageContainer).foo(anyIndex);
}
```

I got a NullPointerException since 'messages' is null. I tried to inject the mock by using @InjectMocks, however this case is not supported since not every parameters of the constructor are declared as members.

I also tried to set the 'messages' field by using WhiteBox

```
    Whitebox.setInternalState(messageContainer, MessageChain[].class, PowerMockito.mock(MessageChain[].class));
```

but I got a compile error since setInternalState only supports (Object, Object, Object) and not Object[].

Is there any possible way to mock a private final field?

Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: The constructor for MessageChain won't compile... did you leave out the varargs parameter?  One way or another it has a typo.  Once it's corrected I think I can help you.

Comment: Are you mocking `MessageContainer` or are you trying to construct a real `MessageContainer` with a mocked `MessageChain`? It's unclear from your question.

Comment: @TJamesBoone: yes i leaved out the other parameters of the MessageContainer. I just made an example to show what I want to do.

Comment: @TomG: I'm trying to mock MessageContainer. I just updated my question and hope it is clearer now. Thank you :)

Comment: A `NullPointerException` from `foo` should be impossible. You are not invoking the real implementation of `foo` since you have a mocked instance of `MessageContainer`. Please show the entire test class.

Comment: @TomG: Oh, I'm sorry, I called the real method using Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(messageContainer).foo(anyIndex);

Comment: @TannenBee I think you are missing the point of mocking then. Why are you mocking the `MessageContainer` if you will invoke the real method? Either stub it with `when()` or construct a real instance.

Comment: @TomG: thanks for your reply. I will make some more thoughts about it. But how would you mock the MessageContainer and assert against it? Since MessageContainer is a third party code which my unit under test invokes. Therefore, I would like to test whenever my unit invokes foo(), the message should be created and stored correctly.
I know some people say rather testing third party code I should only check if the foo() method is invoked. However, i would like to make a deeper test (sort of pre-integration test).Thus, i wanted to mock MessageChain and assert against it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your edits and comments, I would say mocking this class and verifying the method was invoked is sufficient.

If it is third-party code, you should rely **only** on its method signature, which comprises the class's public API. Otherwise you are coupling your tests too tightly to something you have no control over. What do you do when they decide to use a `Collection` instead of an array?

Simply write:

```
MessageContainer container = mock(MessageContainer.class);
//Your code here...
verify(container).foo(obj);
```

Comment: However, I have one more question. What if my unit calculates the parameter for foo, in this case the 'index' and I can't access it to pass to foo(). Would I just write: "verify(container).foo(anyInt)?". What if i want to test whether the index was created correctly? Example:
MyUnit unitUnderTest = new MyUnit();
unitUnderTest.createMessage(); // in this method the index is created and foo() is called
MessageContainer container = mock(MessageContainer.class);
verify(container).foo(anyInt());// how to test if the correctly index was created?

Comment: If you know what index the `MyUnit` class should create, you can use that number in the `verify` call instead of the `anyInt()` matcher.